# How to get and set Autocomplete Multiple values?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-material-ui-form-validator

I following this guild made a textfield.
But i can not got this field value,
Any suggestions?

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#multiple-values

```
 const categories = [
   {id:1, name: "blog"},
   {id:2, name: "music"},
   {id:3, name: "video"},
]
 const [category, setCategory]: any = useState([]);

 <Autocomplete
                                            multiple
                                            limitTags={1}
                                            value={category}
                                            onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                                                setCategory([
                                                    ...category,
                                                    newValue
                                                ]);
                                            }}
                                            id="category-filter"
                                            options={categories}
                                            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                                            renderInput={(params) => (
                                                <TextField {...params} label="Category" placeholder="categories" />
                                            )}

                                        />
```

Comment: It is unclear from your example where you component begins and where it ends. Please provide a complete reproducible example, and explain what you're trying to achieve, and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `newValue` in onChange handler is already an array of selected options, so you can just set it into the `category` simply.
Also since each option is an object, you have to add `isOptionEqualToValue` attribute to tell the component how to compare the option to the selected value. The code is as follows:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Autocomplete, TextField } from "@mui/material";

export const Test = () => {
  const categories = [
    { id: 1, name: "blog" },
    { id: 2, name: "music" },
    { id: 3, name: "video" }
  ];
  const [category, setCategory] = useState([]);
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      limitTags={1}
      value={category}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        setCategory(newValue);
      }}
      id="category-filter"
      options={categories}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Category" placeholder="categories" />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```